# syntax error, unexpected T_USE, expecting T_FUNCTION in my SauceLabs test case

Tags: phpunit, saucelabs

I tried following the SauceLabs PHP tutorial: https://docs.saucelabs.com/tutorials/php/

I tried to make it run on Windows. So I followed every step until I have to run this command:

```
vendor\bin\phpunit.bat WebDriverDemo.php
```

This generates an error: *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_USE, expecting T_FUNCTION in C:\xampp\htdocs\sauce-tutorial\vendor\sauce\sausage\src\Sauce\Sausage\WebDriverTestCase.php
 on line 6*

So I tried looking at WebDriverTestCase.php on line 6 and this is the code:

namespace Sauce\Sausage;

```
abstract class WebDriverTestCase extends \PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    use TestCase; // this is line 6
}
```

Whats wrong with this code? I changed nothing, I only tried to run what the tutorial suggests. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use PHP but on the basis of what I found with a Google search, I'd suggest making sure you are running the code with PHP 5.4 or later. In the cases I found on the web using an older version of PHP seemed to be the cause of that error.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. PHP v5.3.29. My class isn't abstract but does extend from another class. I have another class in the same project that uses traits but doesn't extend another class. That one works fine. Is it a problem with extending classes?